# AutoHotkey executing commands after GuiClose without hitting the X button

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

My goal was to use what I have learned to make a GUI with three buttons to open the corresponding .ahk file. With my code so far it works perfectly until I add the code to close the script when I close the GUI. When I add this code...

```
GuiClose: 
    ExitApp
    return
```

to the top, it makes the script close itself as soon as it runs. But I only want that bit of code to run if I press the X button on the GUI. What am I missing here?

All of my code:

```
#SingleInstance, force

GuiClose: 
    ExitApp
    return

Gui, Add, Button, y0 x0 w32 h32 g1, 1
Gui, Add, Button, y0 x45 w32 h32 g2, 2
Gui, Add, Button, y0 x90 w32 h32 g3, 3
Gui, Show, x800 y50 w150 h100, The Gui
return

1:
    run, open "C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned.ahk"
    return

2:
    run, open "C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned2.ahk"
    return

3:
    run, open "C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned3.ahk"
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The** **[auto-exection section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)** (= top of the script before the first hotkey, hotstring, return,  OnMessage or GUI definition) **executes automatically when the script starts**.

Therefore you cannot define a **[label](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm)** (subroutine) in this section.

```
#SingleInstance, force

Gui, Add, Button, y0 x0 w32 h32 g1, 1
Gui, Add, Button, y0 x45 w32 h32 g2, 2
Gui, Add, Button, y0 x90 w32 h32 g3, 3
Gui, Show, x800 y50 w150 h100, The Gui

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

1:
    run, C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned.ahk
return

2:
    run, C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned2.ahk
return

3:
    run, C:\users\Milquetoast\Desktop\learned3.ahk
return

GuiClose: 
    ExitApp
return
```